# UIInterpolatingMotionEffect Parallax Effect Swift 2 iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parallax, uimotioneffect

I am trying to create a parallax effect such as the iPhone homescreen where the background moves as your tilt your phone. I have so far achieved this, but I have one problem still. After I tilt my phone and the background moves, it very slowly moves back into position of being centered.

It's not the constraints. I removed the center x/y constraint and it still slid back slowly as if it was re-calibrating to the new position. The only other constraint is the ratio. So it's not the constraints.

any ideas?

The code is simple:

```
let leftRightMin = CGFloat(-50.0)
let leftRightMax = CGFloat(50.0)
let upDownMin = CGFloat(-35.0)
let upDownMax = CGFloat(35.0)

let leftRight = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", type: 
                                   UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType.TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
leftRight.minimumRelativeValue = leftRightMin
leftRight.maximumRelativeValue = leftRightMax

let upDown = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.y", type:      
                                     UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType.TiltAlongVerticalAxis)
upDown.minimumRelativeValue = upDownMin
upDown.maximumRelativeValue = upDownMax

let fxGroup = UIMotionEffectGroup()
fxGroup.motionEffects = [leftRight, upDown]

backgroundImage.addMotionEffect(fxGroup)
```

Any ideas why it slowly centers the image back after tilting and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried removing the constraints and making sure that that is the problem?

Comment: @mhillsman I just edited the post. I removed the center x/y constraint and it still slowly slid back to its place as if it was re-calibrating to the new position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the behavior of `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`. You'll notice it also happens on the home screen, and everywhere else in the system that the effect is used.

It does this because sometimes the user will move their device in such a way that the content interpolates to the maximum position, but does not return to the center or resting position. This means that the position that was once the maximum interpolating position is now the resting center, so the content must move back to its original position in case the device moves again and the effect can continue.

I did not find any mention of this behavior in the [UIInterpolatingMotionEffect documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInterpolatingMotionEffect_class/index.html), but it can be observed everywhere the system uses the effect.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks I was afraid it was just normal behavior. Yeah it saves it from showing white space ever probably. I just didn't like how fast it was moving back. It was noticeable to the eye. On the home screen you have to really watch to notice.